# Gradle: Hot deploy changes to a dependency

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, jrebel, hotdeploy

I have an environment where I have a java(spring mvc) webapp being developed by an n-member team on intellij with gradle as the build agent. This project has a dependency that is also being developed by the same team. The dependency is published to a repository from where it is read by the spring mvc app. What happens is that everytime there is a change to the dependency code, the spring app code has to be refreshed to include the latest version of the dependency code. So, the question is that is there a way to do a code swap at runtime in the dependency code and have it take affect in a debug session, pretty much like what JRebel does except that it needs to do it in the dependency code.

Any views on this would be highly appreciated.

P.S- I tagged gradle and jrebel because there might be a way to achieve this via this tech stack.

Comment: Why go to such lengths? Isn't it easier to create a script to update and redeploy the dependent projects?

Comment: Well, that can be done. But the whole point is that while debugging, can the dependency code be modified and swapped. I dont think with a script this can be achieved. May I am wrong. Please advise.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools that can do wat you're asking. Is it to much work to re-run the application? If the dependency version has a `-SNAPSHOT` suffix maven will always fetch/download the latest version from the repositories.

Comment: I dont think I need a tool. Maybe a different approach in how the spring application reads the dependency code is what is required.

Comment: `-SNAPSHOT` is a maven thing. I have not had luck with it in gradle. Re-running the application is what is being done as of now. But I am looking for a better(faster) way to do this. I am trying to do is avoid the situation mentioned here http://i.stack.imgur.com/gtCJT.jpg

Comment: If you turn app and lib into a single multi-project Gradle build, you can import the whole thing into IntelliJ and use hot code swap in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

JRebel can monitor the jars, though it is not super efficient. In rebel.xml configuration file you can specify a [<jar>](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html#jar) tag pointing to the location of the dependency in the file system.

A better approach would be to actually work with sources, so that you deploy the dependency with [rebel.xml](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html#) that points to the location where the compiled classes are, and then work with the dependency as with source, doing pull/update from version control when needed and compiling the changes. If your compiler is incremental, then it would compile only the changed classes and JRebel wouldn't have to reload too many classes at once, but only the changes.

Comment: Anton, I kind of partially agree with your comment. Deploying the dependency via rebel.xml seems like I am now dividing the responsibility of deploying the dependencies at two places. It certainly seems doable though.